# Using Android Mock Locations in Google Navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Im trying to create a research application with improved locations for guidance of people with visual impairments

I found good examples of how to implement a mock location service provider on the web and this part of the application is working fine,  reading locations from a test file

However I'm struggling with the combination of  MockLocations and the Google Navigation App. Even though I provide all the parameters in the MockLocations (Latitude, Longitude, TimeStamp, Bearing, Velocity, Accuracy and Altitude), and I fix the provider to GPS_PROVIDER,  I still cannot  see my location moving across the map in Google Maps Navigation Mode.

It looks to me that the Google Navigation application is designed to work standalone and it is somehow hard coded to use the phone internal GPS chip. So, it requests the locations from the Location API with a frequency that we don’t even know and must have its own way to handle situations when the GPS is unavailable.

What I still do not know is why the Google Navigation app works fine with the MockLocations in the visualization/localization part and not in the navigation one.

Anyone had this problem before and can give a clue of how to solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to mock locations? If so, ther are some aplications in google play to mock path and locations. Enable developer settings also